# Is there any incoming message queue add-on for Kannel?

Tags: queue, kannel

I have kannel working with sqlbox (postgresql as db backend). Any incoming message will be forwarded to a receive_message listener. The listener will then process the message (query the db, etc). It's a pretty straight forward system, which obviously will break with high load.

One solution for high load scenarios is to put a queue in the middle of the system. I've been reading about a few queuing system, such as RabbitMQ and Beanstalk, but I can't imagine something hasn't been created like this specifically for kannel.

Is there such thing out there? Or distributed queuing system is my best bet? If yes, which one  would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Kannel in my previous gig and I spoke with the main contributors. At the moment, there is no queuing mechanism with the exception of a db, but there has been talks about that. It's important to mentioned that we used Kannel in production with a load of 200 msg/sec with no a problems. The architecture that we implemented was using the straight SMSBox HTTP protocol and putting ActiveMQ to get those messages into a queue.

Let me know if that helps!
Regards,
Marcelo